# Weekly Group by not including Sunday

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am grouping the data by week in the following queries

```
 select id,sum(quantity) ,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0, [createddate]), 0) from table1 where    
 createddate >= '2017-10-02' and createddate <= '2017-11-12'  
 and [id] = 111      
 group by [id] , dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0, [createddate]), 0)
```

Its grouping the data upto Sat i.e. Mon - Sat, not Mon to Sun. Can someone explain what I am missing.

I cannot change the database start day

Sample data is :

- 02/10/2017 9.00
- 03/10/2017 10.50
- 04/10/2017 10.00
- 08/10/2017 1.00

Comment: could u show sample data ?

Comment: edited the question, added sample data

Comment: "Specifying SET DATEFIRST has no effect on DATEDIFF. DATEDIFF always uses Sunday as the first day of the week to ensure the function is deterministic." This from the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql.

Comment: How can I fix this so that it include sunday

Comment: @AnkeshKumar check out my answer

Comment: ok, i will and update you

Answer (score 0):

You could group by week number instead:

```
 group by [id] , datepart(ISO_WEEK, [createddate])
```

ISO weeks start on Monday.

Comment: thanks, what how can I get the date in select  for Modnay

Answer (score 0):

The first day of the week is based on your language settings (default value is us_english is 7 (Sunday)). And SET **DATEFIRST** has no effect on **DATEDIFF**

You can try this query instead

```
set DATEFIRST 1

select id,sum(quantity) ,dateadd(wk, datediff(wk,0, [createddate]), 0) from table1 where    
createddate >= '2017-10-02' and createddate <= '2017-11-12'  
and [id] = 111
group by [id] , dateadd(dd,(-1)*(datepart(dw,[createddate])-1),[createddate])

set DATEFIRST 7
```

**Updated**:

```
dateadd(dd,(-1)*(datepart(dw,[createddate])-1),[createddate])
```

It will return the Monday of the week as your original query.